# Merging entities in TypeORM

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to TypeORM and databases overall and I have simple question.

What is the way to 'merge' entities?
For example:

I have two entities, Product and Producer:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column("int")
    producer_id: number;

    @Column()
    producer: //I want show producer data here

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
    name: string;

}


@Entity()
export class Producer {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    logo: string;

}
```

As you can see, in Product entity I have `producer_id` property which contains ID of producer.
When I'm loading the product I want TypeORM to search through producers, get one with Id matching `producer_id` in Product and store it in `producer` property.

Maybe my question is little bit embroiled but I hope you'll get the point.

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're looking for a one-to-many relation (one producer many products).

Check [this doc](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) from typeorm for further info. But basically do the following:

```js
@Entity()
export class Product {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column("int")
    producer_id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Producer, producer => producer.product)
    producer: Producer

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
    name: string;

}


@Entity()
export class Producer {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    logo: string;

    @OneToMany(type => Product, product => product.producer)
    products: Product[]
}
```

And then in your queries specify `relations` to fetch:

```js
productRepository.find({ relations: ["producer"] });
```

I'm not an user of typeorm, but it should be something like that